# Как сделать конструкцию try-except?

Tags: python, исключения, sqlite3

Нужно чтобы рассылка не падала с ошибкой если пользователь заблокировал его. Как это сделать?

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['sendall'])
def dist(message):

   user_id = message.from_user.id

   if user_id == -----------:
       conn = connecting()
       cursor = conn.cursor()
       cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM login_id")
       results = cursor.fetchall()

       message_to_send = message.text[message.text.find(' '):]

       for result in results:
           bot.send_message(result[0], message_to_send)

       conn.close()
   else:
       bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Команда только сторого для создателя!')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй просто каждый раз используя bot.send_message() заключать это в try:

```
try:
    bot.send_message(result[0], message_to_send)
except:
    pass
```

Comment: Нехорошо полностью подавлять ошибки без их логирования куда-нибудь. Ещё нехорошо перехватывать KeyboardInterrupt и SystemExit